# Balancing Chemical Equations + predicting products

Tags: organic-chemistry

How do I predict the products and balance the equation:

Li(s)+N2(g)---___

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic in its current state. Please see [How do I ask homework question on Chemistry S.E.](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange).

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Finally, we have an important policy: your questions (especially [homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/189)), should show your own work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ce{Li_{(s)} + N2_{(g)}}$ react (I am not sure if they will or not), the product will be $\ce{LiN}$ and the balanced reaction will be:

$\ce{2 Li_{(s)} + N2_{(g)} -> 2 LiN}$

See [this tutorial](http://antoine.frostburg.edu/chem/senese/101/reactions/faq/predicting-products-nicl2-nh42s.shtml), it contains all the steps you should follow to predict the products when formula of reactants are given.